# solidity 1024 call stack depth

Tags: solidity, stack

In solidity there are two stacks: a nornal stack and a call stack. stack depth greater than 1024 will report an error.
Question:
(1) Whether call calls its own internal contract function will occupy the depth of the stack？ I think that only call external function will occupy the depth of the stack.
(2) Is the call stack the only one inside the contract, and all the calls to the transaction occupy the stack depth of this unique call stack? Or will a call stack be created for each transaction, and the stack depth of this transaction should not exceed 1024?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to see it that way :

There is only one call depth limit during a transaction execution, currently set at 1024 as you can see [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/interpreter.go#L113). This is not a stack as in stack memory space, just a **call depth** limit. This value is shared and incremented across the whole execution chain initiated by a transaction.

Each **external** call (`call`, `callcode`, `delegatecall`, `staticcall`) has its own EVM stack ( memory space ) as you can see [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/interpreter.go#L136) , this one can only grow to manage 1024 words, I couldn't find the explicit check but [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/440c9fcf75d9d5383b72646a65d5e21fa7ab6a26/core/vm/stack.go#L52) piece of code mentions the stack push limit.

> (1) Whether call calls its own internal contract function will occupy the depth of the stack？ I think that only call external function will occupy the depth of the stack.

If a contract does an internal call, there is no increment to the call depth as it only applies to external calls. However, this will take some more slots in the stack to save some important values, such as the return address.

> (2) Is the call stack the only one inside the contract, and all the calls to the transaction occupy the stack depth of this unique call stack? Or will a call stack be created for each transaction, and the stack depth of this transaction should not exceed 1024?

The (external) call depth of this transaction should not exceed 1024, but each external call has its own interpreter with its own stack, those individual stacks are all limited to 1024 words.

Since [EIP-150](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-150) only 63/64 of the total remaining gas can be provided to an external call, you can see it as an additional external call depth limit that is dependent of the amount of gas initially provided with the tx.

You can see for yourself with the following contract :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.17;

contract Recurse {

    function recurse(uint256 depth) external {

        // Each call takes at least 3 slots in the stack
        uint256 placeHolder1 = 1;
        uint256 placeHolder2 = 2;
        uint256 placeHolder3 = 3;

        if(depth > 0) {
            this.recurse(depth - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to increase the block gas limit quite a bit ( 3000000000000, ) but calling `recurse` with `depth` > 1024 will revert, any value below that is fine.

With at least 3 words per call, this makes 1024 * 3 words in total, which is above the 1024 stack word limit but since each execution context has its own stack this is fine because we actually have 1024 stacks each with at least 3 words.

The call depth being shared across the whole transaction, the 1025th call makes it go beyond the limit resulting in a revert.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Good answer! I have understood. By the way, I have a question.This is the link:https://www.immunebytes.com/blog/size-limit-in-smart-contracts/. I dont know what is his attack logic. He calls attack(),  it will revert when count = 1024, but others can also call resetInvestment(). What is his target? I want to get more info. Thx bro.

Comment: I try your code in Remix just now. I input 50,100,200 to recurse(uint256), but London VM revert. That's strange, why such a small number causes a revert?

Comment: This code is extremely gas comsuming, you need to increase the block gas limit ( and actually It's highly probable that it just crashes Remix because it will block the nodeJS event loop afaik )